Button hide TextFormField
I have button save inside bottom Sheet, after clicking on txt7 button SAVE hide field. I always want to show the SAVE button on the page.

  Scaffold(
    bottomSheet: SAVE_BUTTON here
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Label 1',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  ),
                  MyTextInputChange(
                    controller: txt1,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    enable: true,
                    autofocus: false,
                    required: false,
                    onChange: (value) {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                  .............
                      

Any solution, how push txt7 above for the height of the button SAVE?

You can use the TextField' or TextFormField's scrollPadding property.
TextFormField(scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 50.0))
Just add a new parameter to your custom input widget, and set it for your TextField or TextFormField.
Note: You must set more than the default 20 for the bottom edge inset.
Docs:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/scrollPadding.html

Tnx for help, I'm only add scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 90.0)   and    SizedBox(height: 75)  after last TextFormField's
